# Blockchain synchronization never ends (Geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Ask me a question, please ... I installed Geth to mine Ethreum, I made all the settings correctly, but the synchronization does not end. I used the eth.syncing command and believed that when currentBlock reached HighestBlock, blockchain synchronization would end. However, when the currentBlock comes close to the HighestBlock value, the HighestBlock increases the value. I don't know when it will end. My computer has an i5 processor, 8GB Ram and I am saving the blockchain on an external hard drive.

(I used the google translator).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your external hard drive is the culprit.

Ethereum nodes must be saved on a fast SSD. If your external hard drive is slow, or if your connection to the drive is slow, it may be why it never syncs.

Or you did not wait long enough. It can take days to do a "fast" sync. A "full" or "archive" sync would take even longer.

Comment: It races ahead to get block headers quickly and then seems to stall as it downloads the data for all of those blocks.

Comment: Maybe, but with good hardware that would end after some time. If it "never" ends, it is perpetually syncing and never catching up.

Comment: He didn't say how patient he's been or if it seems busy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I waited for more than a week. How could I get the sync status? How do you know what the estimated time would take?

Comment: To know the sync status, you have to open the geth console (use geth attach in another terminal window): https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console - Then, type eth.syncing in the console. If you see false, it's done. If you see numbers, you are still syncing.